# "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger" error after upgrading Spring Boot from 2.4.6 to 2.6.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j

I updated the spring-boot-starter-parent version from 2.4.6 to 2.6.6 to resolve some security vulnerabilities with spring-beans and spring-security-web
But when I try to start the application after updating the Spring Boot version, I could see the below log4j warning messages

*log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger {class name}

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.*

Also, no logger messages are getting printed in the console (I haven't changed anything in the log4j2.xml file)
Please let me know the cause and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates that something is trying to use Log4J 1.x.

It's likely that you have some transitive dependency that requires it. You will need to use your build tool to figure out what that is (for example, with Maven use `mvn dependency:tree`) and then exclude that transitive dependency.

You also need to add the Log4J 1.x bridge JAR to your build, as described [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html), or whatever is trying to use Log4J 1 will fail with an exception.

Comment: Thanks for response. In my case I solved the error by replacing log4j-1.2-api with log4j-api and log4j-core dependencies. But the error shows when the log4j-1.2-api is included. It would be helpful if you could share some insight on how log4j works? Thanks in advance